# Navigate between Threads in PyCharm

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pycharm, pyzmq

I recently move to PyCharm Professional in my company.

Before that I was on PyCharm Community.

We have two programs which communicate between them with PyZMQ. Each of them are open in two separate window of PyCharm.

With the PyCharm 2017.3.7 Community Version we are able to navigate between the threads with the debugger. But with most recent versions we can't do that anymore so we are stuck on this 2017 version. Is there a way to unlock us from this ?

I tried to tick and un-ticking "Gevent compatible" but the issue is still there. I read many forums but I didn't find any answer.

Thank you,

Navigate between two pieces of software who communicate with pyzmq. These two pieces of software are open in two separate window of pyzmq (on the same PC).